# View Spinner in Android from php url

Tags: php, android, spinner

I'm a beginner to android development. I wanna view a list from a php url. And view it using a spinner in android. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Learn from these link...

[Link 1](http://androidexample.com/Restful_Webservice_Call_And_Get_And_Parse_JSON_Data-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=101&aaid=123)

[http://codeoncloud.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-mysql-php-json-tutorial.html

http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/13239/android-mysql-php-json-part-6-json-parsing-and-android-design/

Comment: The link you gave me is for listview. I'm asking for spinner. :/

Comment: Hey just go the tutorial how they are loading into listView from php web service if you understood well then you can load it in spinner, see some spinner tutorials also.